# Why i can't use the delete operator if i have created a variable which can be accessed window.x?

Tags: javascript, variables, object, delete-operator

Can someone explain the difference?

```
var x = 5; delete window.x; false

y = 5; delete window.y; true
```

They both get attached to the `window` object but i'm unable to delete the one with the `var` deceleration.

Answer (score 2):

If you check **[MDN `delete` Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete#Description)**, you can see that:

> Any property declared with var cannot be deleted from the global scope or from a function's scope.

So you can't delete the variable `x` because you declared it with `var` in the global scope (`window`).

Comment: Thanks, i found all the answers in your link!

Comment: @DavisDavis You are welcome, glad it helps.